# Getting the privacy setting of a status message?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, status, privacy

Does anyone know if it's possible to query the privacy settings for status updates? I know you can get them for photo albums, but for my application it would be useful to be able to pull up a random status message from a while back and say "You shared this post with everyone, would you still do this today?" to see how people's attitudes to sharing online change.

I'm not after anything fancy, just "friends", "public" or "custom" would be great.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a user's own status updates (i.e the person who's using your app) this is easily obtained, there's a `privacy` field on the Post objects, and example from my /feed connection is:

```
 "privacy": {
        "description": "Friends; Except: Restricted", 
        "value": "CUSTOM", 
        "friends": "ALL_FRIENDS", 
        "deny": "< ID of my restricted list >"
}
```

If it's on a friend of the current user's wall i'm not sure if/how to retrieve the same data

Comment: What about if you're using the /statuses connection? It'd be preferable to **just** get status messages without needing to throw any stuff away. (Although if that isn't possible, thank you!)

Comment: i haven't checked, but the return type on /statuses should be the same as on /feed

Comment: They don't seem to have a "privacy" attribute. (Although it'd make sense if they did)

Comment: huh, so it doesn't - i think the feed connection is probably what you want, based on what you said in the question about your use-case i don't think the distinction between 'text-only status message' and 'other thing posted by the user' is that significant

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll set this as accepted unless someone else comes along with a major brainwave before I go for lunch. ;D